# Tutorial for Parsing Images from Url in Iphone

Tags: iphone

Can anyone  help me out with a simple Tutorial demonstrating the Parsing of image from url in IPhone

Comment: What do you mean with "parsing of images"? Download the data, parse an HTLM source and search for images?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your-url-to-image-goes-here"];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am very much new to the IPhone so i was just looking for some tutorial which could give me the Clear Idea.
If u know any such link it would be great if u forward that to me thanks one again for the help.